# What kind of light bulb does this lamp use?

Tags: lighting

It is an old lamp from IKEA

[image]

Here is a picture of the inside of it

[image]

I could not remember what kind of light bulb it uses. Can anyone able to identify the right kind?

It would be even greater if you link back to the IKEA catalogue.

Measurement of the socket: 1 inch at the widest

**Edit:**

1. Photo of a label at the bottom

[image]

2. Yes, I live in Australia

Comment: You've been given the information you need. The rest is up to you. We're not going to achieve 100% confidence with what we have to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IKEA provides [a tool](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/lighting/tools/find_the_right_light_bulb/) to help identify bulb size. The one you need is listed as a group: (E12, E14, E17 or SES)

The 12 in E12, for example, means a diameter of 12mm. This is just a bit under 1/2". Carefully measure the size of the threaded cylinder and you should know which size you need. E14 will be about 9/16". E17 will be about 11/16". E14 and SES are the same.

E14/SES seems to be the most common and is probably your huckleberry.

Answer (score 2):

Edison screw (ES) is correct, in Australia this will be almost certainly an E14 size.  This is the commonest small size. You might have one in your fridge to test. Make sure the rest of the bulb can fit! I live in Aust.